# How to create a common GKSession with a singleton?

Tags: singleton, gksession

A bit confused here... I have an app with multiple views, and each view needs to share a common GKSession. I would like to implement this with a singleton pattern.

My confusion: should the singleton class be a subclass of GKSession OR rather, should the singleton class be an NSObject which is a GKSessionDelegate? I am inclined to believe the proper pattern is to implement the class as a delegate.

thanks...

Comment: It completely depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Let's say I have two views, viewA and viewB. viewA will establish a bluetooth link with another device and create a GKSession and can send data over the link. viewB will then use that same session to receive data.

Comment: Shouldn't you then put the two views in a view controller and make the view controller the delegate of the `GKSession` object?

Comment: Sorry, I need to be more precise. I have two ViewControllers, viewcontrollerA and viewcontrollerB, and they need to share a common bluetooth link.

Comment: well, then... If you try making the shared object the delegate of the GKSession (which should be its instance variable!), then can you manage it? If so, that should be fine.

Comment: As I am thinking this through, I think it could work both ways. If I create a subclass/shared instance of GKSession, then both view controllers will be delegates (?). But if I create a new class that fully owns the link/session, then the sharedinstance must be the session delegate.

Comment: You can't set multiple objects as the delegate.

Comment: Thanks, then that clearly points to my original leaning. I need a sharedinstance of a class that is the session delegate. The class will contain the delegate methods and methods for sending/receiving data to the two viewcontrollers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18130/discussion-between-dawgless-boyd-and-h2co3)